# how to check if an incoming number data is greater or less than certain limit in firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have `capacity` as a field in my document, I want to ensure the number of capacity doesn't exceed 200000, so in my security rules I set the rules like below

```
request.resource.data.capacity.size() <= 200000
```

it the access will always be denied. whats the correct format to check the number size in firestore security rules ?

Comment: What do you mean by the "number size"? Are you talking about a number field vaue, or the size of an array, or something else? Could you edit the question to give a specific query that should fail with this rule in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the title says "an incoming number data is greater or less than certain limit" I make the assumption that by "check(ing) the number size" you mean checking the number *value*.

If this assumption is correct, you just have to do:

```
  //...
  allow write: if request.resource.data.capacity <= 200000;
  //...
```

You'll find more info in the [Data Validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) section of the doc.

---

Note that `size()` returns the number of characters in the string, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String.html#size